# How to use OSLog in Xcode 12.5.1 or Xcode 13?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, oslog

I have tried using OSLog per documentation in both Xcode versions 12.5 and 13 with similar failure:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import OSLog

struct IdeaListView: View {
    let logger = Logger()
    let x = 42
    logger.info("The answer is \(x)
```

[image]

How is OSLog supposed to work? I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you post images of code, please also copy/paste or type the actual code directly into the post as text (within a code block). [Code in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Posts in which code is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this

```
Logger.info(.....
```

inside a function or a block not in `struct` level , e.x

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let logger = Logger()
    let x = 12
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding().onTapGesture {
                logger.info("This is a message \(x)")
            }
    }
}
```